# How to build a mining pool on private chain?

Tags: private-blockchain, mining-pools

I have built up a private chain between by computers. And now I want to make one of these computers as a mining pool in this private chain. could you please tell me how to achieve this function?

Comment: Did you mean you want to use one of the computers as miner in your private chain?

Comment: No, I want to use one as a mining pool so that my Rraspberry Pi will connect to it and Rraspberry Pi will be a miner for this pool. could you please tell me how can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a mining software pool like [Open Source Ethereum Minig Pool](https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool)

Answer (score 1):

I've used this in the past to set up private pools to mine ethereum and forks.
https://github.com/dataspark-co/eth-pool-docker-infra

It's the Open Ethereum Pool, but containerized with docker.